# Recursion related: Product of two numbers

Tags: java, recursion, product

I thought this would be relatively easy but running it, gives wrong result. It may be the initialization of the result variable but I cant seem to be able to modify the code such as to be correct. Here is my progress so far.

```
public class test 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int num1 = 10;
      int num2 = 4;

      int res = product(num1, num2);

      System.out.println(res); 
   }

   public static int product(int n1, int n2)
   {
      int result = 0 ;

      if (n2 > 0)
      {
          result = result + n1 ;
          product(n1,n2-1) ;
      }
         return result ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**better solution**
**here**

```
public static int product(int n1, int n2) 
           { 
              if (n2 > 1) 
              { 
                  n1 += product(n1,n2-1) ; 
              } 
                 return n1; 
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int product(int n1, int n2)
   {
      int result = 0 ;

      if (n2 > 0)
      {
          result = result + n1 ;
          product(n1,n2-1) ;
      }
         return result ;
   }
```

In this code, you are making result = 0 everytime you call the method, which you obviously don't want to do. Rather, you should initialize it first in the main code, then pass it in, like this

```
public static int product(int n1, int n2, int result)
```

Then when you do recursion, simply pass result in every time!

Like so:

```
product(n1, n2-1, result);
```

Your main should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int num1 = 10;
      int num2 = 4;
      int result = 0;

      int res = product(num1, num2, result);

      System.out.println(res); 
   }
```

What this will do, is make the value of result availible to your function, initialized.

Edit:

When doing recursion, we must remember to set the thing we want returned to the function we call, rather than just calling the function again, otherwise, the initial answer will be returned (in this case the value of n1).

Do it like so:

```
     public static int product(int n1, int n2, int result)
   {

      if (n2 > 0)
      {
          result = result + n1 ;
          result = product(n1,n2-1, result) ;
      }
         return result ;
   }
}
```

Comment: but how i am supposed to call this method from the main, having my res variable set to 0?

Comment: this solution keeps returning the value of n1 as a final result. i mean if its 10, the programs shows 10, if its 18 the program shows 18

Comment: That is rather strange, let me try compiling it, I didnt evaluate the actual recursion part, just the passing of paramaters.

Comment: @SergiosSchizas the recursion is correct, it's simply returning the wrong value, give me a little to figure it out.

Comment: ok this works, but i dont seem to get the logic behind it. im a bit confused.

Comment: When you're doing recursion, you have a choice, either return a variable that you use in the calculation, like that other answer, or return a different variable completely, ie: Result. Result gets set each time you call the function. First 10, then 20, then 30, then 40. When you return result at the last level, it returns 40, but then, on the level below it was saved as 30, so it returns 30, then 20, then 10, which is what you see. So, to get the proper value being sent back, you have to send the value through the levels.

Comment: At the final run through of the method, the value of return is 40, so that get returned. On the next level down, the value was 30, but gets set to 40, and that is returned. The next level was 20, gets set to 40 and is returned, and the same until it's returned to the main program.

Think of it like a stack with different numbers in it, and as you take off the top of the stack, you're putting the value in to the lower one.

Comment: it is like Inception! i would prefer it if it was a dream though :)

Comment: That is a great way to look at it lmfao

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test{
static int result;
public static void main(String...x){
    int num1 = 10;
      int num2 = 4;

      int res = product(num1, num2);

      System.out.println(res); 
   }

   public static int product(int n1, int n2)
   {


      if (n2 > 0)
      {
          result = result + n1 ;
          product(n1,n2-1) ;
      }
         return result ;
   }
}
```

Your problem is with the variable result, every time you call the method, the variable initialize it with zero.

Comment: Declaring it as a global variable isn't the best style, passing it through makes more sense.

Comment: may i ask why you declared the result outside the main? if you do so, the variable does not need initialisation?

Comment: @SergiosSchizas He is declaring the result as a field, or a global variable. This works, but is very bad style in java. You should use the solution I gave you higher up instead, it's the more "typical" way to do recursion.

Comment: @SergiosSchizas If I don't do so, then result will not be available to the product() method. Symbol not found error will come.

Comment: Not to mention that he should have initialized it to 0, since that code would very likely compile error.

Comment: @LucasMarcelli why compiler error, default initialization is there, right!

Comment: @ChandraSekhar You're setting result = result + (n1), but on the first pass, result has no value, how can you add Null to an Int? You should have put static int result = 0; Regardless, declaring a field is still not a good way to go about this, especially if this is a static main class rather than a java class, it teaches bad style.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter solution

```
public static int product(int n1, int n2) {
    return n2 == 0 ? 0 : n1 + product(n1, n2-1);
}
```

An optimised was of do it (which is similar to how multiplication is actually implemented in a CPU) is

```
public static int product(int n1, int n2) {
    if (n2 == 0) return 0;
    int p = product(n1, n2 >> 1);
    return p + p + ((n2 & 1) == 0 ? 0 : n1);
}
```

This will recurse up to 31 times, where as the first solution might recurse over 2 billion times.